# How to output only dev names and types in lsblk?

Tags: lsblk

I intend to get a list of all partitions with their corresponding types but arranged in the proper tree order.

This is what I get with `lsblk -o NAME,TYPE -i`

```
sda             disk
|-sda1          part
|-sda2          part
|-sda3          part
| |-2cl-root    lvm
| |-2cl-swap    lvm
| |-2cl-home    lvm
| |-2cl-data2   lvm
| `-2cl-data4   lvm
|-sda4          part
| |-1cl00-data3 lvm
|   |-asf1      lvm
|   `-asf2      lvm  
`-sda5          part
sdb             disk
`-sdb1          part
  `-md126       raid1
sdc             disk
`-sdc1          part
  `-md126       raid1
sdd             disk
`-sdd1          part
  `-md127       raid0
    `-3-data6   lvm
sde             disk
`-sde1          part
  `-md127       raid0
    `-3-data6   lvm
sr0             rom
```

But I want it to display this way

```
sda             disk
sda1            part
sda2            part
sda3            part
2cl-root        lvm
2cl-swap        lvm
2cl-home        lvm
2cl-data2       lvm
2cl-data4       lvm
sda4            part
1cl00-data3     lvm
asf1            lvm
asf2            lvm  
sda5            part
sdb             disk
sdb1            part
md126           raid1
sdc             disk
sdc1            part
md126           raid1
sdd             disk
sdd1            part
md127           raid0
3-data6         lvm
sde             disk
sde1            part
md127           raid0
3-data6         lvm
sr0             rom
```

I tried with `-s -l` option, but the results became much weirder. How do I format it properly, but still get the correct order as the tree? I would not mind if there is only 1 space between name and type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
lsblk -o NAME,TYPE -n -i -r
```

If you cannot ask `lsblk` to format the output as you want, you can pipe it and change it.

For example, if the tab is really important:

```
lsblk -o NAME,TYPE -n -i -r | tr ' ' '\t'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I did not get the correct order. Ex. under sde we have sde1.

Comment: @JonesG there seems to be no differences in the order in your question. And `cut` will only _clean up_ the output, the order does not change. If `lsblk -r` lists them right, so will the pipe through `cut`.

Comment: I was wrong with sde and sde1. In my question, if you look at sda3 it is followed by several sub partitions, then sda4. With `lsblk -r` sda3 is followed by sda4

Comment: ok, I updated the answer.

Comment: there is a bug in `lsblk -r` in my version that is why I am getting a wrong order, it was fixed in 2.35.2.

Comment: Who would've thought? Thanks for sharing the info.